# Limit of a sequence involving roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can I find the limit of the following sequence:
$b_n = \sqrt[4]{n^4+n^3} - \sqrt[4]{n^4+1}$?

I succeeded in finding the limits of other sequences involving roots using the binomic formulas but I don't know what to apply to fourth roots.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am sorry, I accidentally changed the terms under the roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for multiplication with the conjugate: $\sqrt a-\sqrt b=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}$.
$$ \begin{align}b_n&=\sqrt[4]{n^4+n^3}-\sqrt[4]{n^4+1}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{n^4+n^3}-\sqrt{n^4+1}}{\sqrt[4]{n^4+n^3}+\sqrt[4]{n^4+1}}\\
&=\frac{(n^4+n^3)-(n^4+1)}{(\sqrt[4]{n^4+n^3}+\sqrt[4]{n^4+1})(\sqrt{n^4+n^3}+\sqrt{n^4+1})}\\
&=\frac{n^3}{(\sqrt[4]{n^4+n^3}+\sqrt[4]{n^4+1})(\sqrt{n^4+n^3}+\sqrt{n^4+1})}\\
&=\frac{1}{(\sqrt[4]{1+n^{-1}}+\sqrt[4]{1+n^{-4}})(\sqrt{1+n^{-1}}+\sqrt{1+n^{-4}})}\\&\to \frac1{(1+1)(1+1)}=\frac14\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks so much! I actually made it all the way to step 4 but then I am a bit weak when it comes to working with roots and I failed to cancel out the $n^3$ so I assumed my appraoch was wrong. Thanks so much for your informative answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $n^4+n^3=\bigg(n+\dfrac14\bigg)^4+\mathcal O\big(n^2\big)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familliar with the notation you are using ("big O"?).

Comment: In this case, it's a second degree polynomial in *n*.